# Chrome devtools does not detect breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug the code below, where a breakpoint is set at the line the the contents `results=results+...`. However, Chrome development tools doesn't stop at the breakpoint. Is there any wrong with this approach?

```
gapi.client.quoteendpoint.listQuote().execute(function(resp) {
  if (!resp.code) {
    resp.items = resp.items || [];
    var result = "";

    for (var i=0;i<resp.items.length;i++) {
      result = result+ resp.items[i].message + "..." + "<b>" + resp.items[i].author + "</b>" + "[" + resp.items[i].id + "]" + "<br/>";
    }

    document.getElementById('listQuotesResult').innerHTML = result;
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the line is reached? Perhaps `resp.items.length` is `0`. Perhaps adding a `console.log('test');` could help

Comment: I can surely say the line is reached because the html is populated with the results.    quick question - when I put the console.log statement - where will it print? How do I look at it?

Comment: Should print to the web console. I use Firefox so that can be reached with the developer view, but I'm not so sure in chrome. There must be a way.

Comment: I tried Firefox and it works fine.  T am not sure why the debugger doesn't  go to breakpoint in chrome.   Thanks for the help.